# Difference between squid and apt-cache server?

Tags: ubuntu, squid

Does any one know what the difference between Squid and apt-cache server in Ubuntu? Cause I'm just familiar with apt-cache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apples and oranges, really.

Squid is a general purpose proxy - you can use this for caching websites in general, filtering or even altering content.

apt-cacher server caches packages, and nothing else -its a nice way to save bandwidth on a network.

From the [manpage](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/apt_cacher)

> Apt-cacher is a caching proxy for Debian packages, allowing a number
>   of computers to share a single local cache. Packages requested from
>   the cache only need to be downloaded from the Debian mirrors once, no
>   matter how many local machines need to install them. This saves
>   internet bandwidth and improves performance for local users, and
>   reduces the load on the mirrors.

Comment: If I want to centralize download packages or just server which direct connected to internet and for client get new packages from server.Which one the suitable for do it ?

Comment: apt-cacher is better. Squid is more if you want to do content management, general caching of web. You might also want to take a look at apt-mirror if you just want to mirror the whole repo.

Comment: you said `mirror the whole repo` ? how it looks like?But for apt-cache doesn't work in my ubuntu 12.04, just like my previous post.

Comment: I can't see your previous post unless i look for it. You asked for the difference - and well squid isn't what you're looking for.